# Is $\{x \in \mathbb{Z} \mid x = 6a + 4 \}$ a subset of $\{y \in \mathbb{Z} \mid y = 18b - 2\}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, examples-counterexamples

Here is the question:

> Let $A = \{x \in \mathbb{Z} \mid x = 6a + 4, \text{for some integer } a\}$
>
> And let $B = \{y \in \mathbb{Z} \mid y = 18b - 2, \text{for some integer } b\}$
>
> Prove or disprove the claim that $A \subseteq B$.

So far, I've managed to do the following:

$6a + 4 = 18b - 2$ by substitution

$6a + 6 = 18b$

$a+1 = 3b$

$b = \frac{a+1}{3}$ by algebra

The solution I read says $b$ is not an integer since $b = \frac{a+1}{3}$ is not an integer and therefore $A \not\subseteq B$. However, for $a = 2, b = 3$. So there is some integer $a$ and $b$ then and therefore $A \subseteq B$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: All you need to disprove the claim is to find one integer in $A$ that isn't in $B$.  That shouldn't be difficult.  Remember:  just finding some integers in $A$ that happen to be in $B$ doesn't tell you much.  You need *every* element of $A$ to be in $B$ in order to have $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: For a problem you may find more challenging, prove or disprove that $B \subseteq A$.

Comment: I suppose I could let $a$ and $b$ be some arbitrary numbers and disprove from there, but I'm trying to figure out why the solution that uses proof by contradiction says $b = \frac{a+1}{3}$ is not an integer. I guess I would understand why they made that conclusion if it stated, "for all integers a" but the question is "for some integer a?

Comment: The solution (at least, as far as you quoted it) is wrong.  Ignore it and think about the answer provided here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before trying to prove the claim, it is helpful to try a few examples to see whether or not it makes sense. This is particularly important as you asked to prove **or disprove** it.

Let's pick a few simple examples of elements in $A$. If the claim is true and $A \subseteq B$, then these should also be elements in $B$.

If we choose $a=0, a=1, a=2$ (just as a starting point), then by substitution, we find that: $$4, 10, 16 \in A$$

We can now check whether or not it makes sense for these elements to also be in the set $B$ (which they must be if the claim is true).

$$\text{If }18b-2 = 4 \text{, then }b = \frac{3}{9}$$

Immediately, we have a problem. We have $4 \in A$ but we cannot have $4 \in B$ since this is only true when $b = \frac{3}{9}$ which is not an integer. So $A \not \subseteq B$ since there are elements of $A$ that are not elements of $B$.

Therefore the claim is **False** (using a proof by counterexample).

---

*Note: we didn't have to consider the element $4$, we could have done the same procedure for the other elements that we found above and this would have also shown the desired result*

Comment: If you want to now the reason why the argument in your post holds, the reason is that we need **every** element of $A$ to be an element of $B$. You correctly found that $b = \frac{a+1}3$. This is *sometimes* valid where $a$ and $b$ are integers. However, there are many examples where this does not work. For example, when $a =1$, then $b= \frac{2}{3}$ according to the formula that you have derived @Zar

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I was getting caught up with the "for some integer $a$" part, thinking that I simply needed one example where $a$ and $b$ are both integers, then therefore $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: @Zar I would also reiterate that you should always look for counter-examples first. I cannot tell you how many times I've answered a question simply by considering simple or trivial cases. It can save you a ton of work chasing dead ends.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate perspective:

$A = \{x \in \mathbb{Z} \mid x = 6a  - 2, \text{for some integer } a\}.$ 
$B = \{y \in \mathbb{Z} \mid y = 18b - 2, \text{for some integer } b\}.$

Every number of the form $~18b~$ can be expressed as $~6a~$ where $~a = 3b.~$  However, the reverse is not true.  That is, if $~a~$ does not happen to be a multiple of $~3,~$ then $~6a~$ can not be expressed as $~18b.~$

So, from this perspective, it is clear that $~B \subseteq A~$ and that an element $~x \in A \setminus B~$ can be constructed by setting $~a~$ to be any integer that is not a multiple of $~3.~$

For example, taking $~a = 1 \implies 4 = x \in A \setminus B.~$

---

A somewhat different perspective is to examine the congruency classes $\pmod{18}$ which may be expressed as

$$\{0,1,2,\cdots,17\}.~$$

The only corresponding congruency class represented by $~B~$ is $~16,~$ while $~A~$ represents the congruency classes of $~4,~10,~16.$